thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6 not working
Why isn't my thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6 working? I've added thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6 to the pom file?. I'm using Spring Security version 6.2.2 and Thymeleaf version 3.1.2.
followed the instructions at https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity/tree/3.1-master but it still doesn't work.
This is my pom file.
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>phone_store</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>phone_store</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.30</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>

this is my html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top" style="color: #6c6d73;background: #f2f4ff;" th:fragment="navbar">
    <div class="container" style="max-width: 872px">
        <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/Home}">
            <img th:src="@{/images/utils/logo.png}" alt="" style="max-width: 130px">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar"
                aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar"
             aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
            <div class="offcanvas-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body">
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active general_Text" aria-current="page" th:href="@{/Home}">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle general_Text" href="#" role="button"
                           data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                           aria-expanded="false">
                            Collection
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 360px">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Iphone</a></li>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SamSung</a></li>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nokia</a></li>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item col-8">
                        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                            <input class="form-control no-border me-2 col-8" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                                   aria-label="Search">
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-center">
                    <li class="nav-item me-1">
                        <a class="nav-link"
                           th:href="@{/Auth/SignIn}" style="cursor: pointer">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-user fa-xl me-1 icon"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-1">
                        <a class="nav-link "
                           href="#" style="cursor: pointer">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping fa-xl me-1 icon"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-1" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                        <a class="nav-link "
                           href="#" style="cursor: pointer">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-door-open fa-xl me-1 icon"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>

*sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" is not working
If the user is authenticated, then the code inside sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" should be executed

works here... what do you expect? Note: no need to specify a version for thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6.

I tried, but it still doesn't work

I have simmiliar issue before where sec:authentication="name" not working for me. After read https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity/tree/3.1-master?tab=readme-ov-file, in order to solve that we need org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect or org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect, and we need configure this dialect on our configuration file.
Here my configuration file:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.addDialect(springSecurityDialect());

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }
}

And here my example code on my html:
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/orders}">Orders</a>
</li>

And all working,
Unauthenticated User:
Unauthenticated User
Authenticated User:
Authenticated User
